# How to remove subscription policy in wso2 apim 4.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have an up and running wso2 apim 4.0.0. I have created some subscription policies in admin portal, then applied them on certain apis on publisher portal. Now if I remove them on admin portal after unchecking on publisher, I am not able to change the api.

The UI of the publisher keeps popping up the message - "Something went wrong when updating the api". Wso2carbon.log prints

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/publisher] [2022-05-18 14:31:38,333] ERROR 
{org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl} - Error while updating 
the API : 008d1f21-56b9-4356-a335-3c190ae9e86c - Specified tier(s) [Minimum] are invalid 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Specified tier(s) [Minimum] are invalid
******************************************************************************************
TID: [-1234] [api/am/publisher] [2022-05-18 14:31:38,499]  WARN 
{org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil} - Unknown tier: Minimum found on API: 
MyApi
```

The question is why it keeps looking for the deleted tier if it is not used (unchecked) in subscriptions on publisher portal?
How to safely delete the custom subscription policy so that I can avoid aforementioned error?

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error trace captured in WSO2 Carbon logs? Also, have you observed any errors during the deletion of the custom subscription policy in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I can also experience the same behavior with the product.
As a workaround, I was successfully able to get the API back as below:

- reload the API if it's not loaded after the deletion
- go to the subscriptions tab of that API
- if there are no subscription policies available as selected select any of them and click save (if there are any selected ones available, just click save)
- Go to the Business Info or Basic Info tab and click Save to see if it still comes

Further preventing deleting subscription policies assigned to APIs I have opened a git issue [1]. You can track the issue there.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/135